# Is it possible to reverse a data order in certain label on Radar Type Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js, radar-chart

[Radar Chart Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfmWq.png)

```
{
    type: 'radar',
                data: {
                  labels: [
                    'N',
                    'G',
                    'A',
                    'L',
                    'P',
                    'I',
                    'T',
                    'V',
                    'X',
                    'S',
                    'B',
                    'O',
                    'R',
                    'D',
                    'C',
                    'Z',
                    'E',
                    'K',
                    'F',
                    'W',
                  ],
                  datasets: [
                    {
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                      data: [5,3,6,6,2,4,3,1,2,7,4,4,5,6,6,7,4,4,4,7],                                                  
                    },
                  ],
                },
```

{
type: 'radar',
data: {
labels: [
'N',
'G',
'A',
'L',
'P',
'I',
'T',
'V',
'X',
'S',
'B',
'O',
'R',
'D',
'C',
'Z',
'E',
'K',
'F',
'W',
],
datasets: [
{
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
data: [5,3,6,6,2,4,3,1,2,7,4,4,5,6,6,7,4,4,4,7],
},
],
},

What I'm expecting is the chart output re-adjusted (reverse data order) on label Z and K. Thank you.

Comment: I think Chart.js is not managing the sort of labels/data because the assumption that is done by the user.

Comment: @user2057925 is there any recommendation for JS library that can manage dataset re-order?

Comment: Maybe simply setting the array to an array instance and then invoke sort method of an array

Comment: @user2057925 can you give me an example for this case?

Comment: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/qBQxEdP